# Oracle SQL - get the row with either NULL or the max value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

I want a where-clause that returns always one row.
If for a query that returns multiple rows one of the values in a specific (nullable DateTime) field is NULL, it should return this row.
If there is no row with a value of NULL, it should return the row with the max-datetime.

For example:

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 |

In this example, the row with ID=2 should be returned.

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 |

And in this example with no NULL row, the ID=1 row should be returned (because it has the highest date).

How is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ID1 has the highest date? They all have the same date (2022-01-01). So, does it matter then which row to return?

Comment: Use any of the linked duplicates and `ORDER BY "DATE" DESC NULLS FIRST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the ID for the highest date, where null is considered higher than any real date. In case of a tie you want the minimum ID. You can use Oracle's `KEEP LAST` for this:

```
select min(id) keep (dense_rank last order by date nulls last) from mytable;
```

Comment: ...it's a good answer +1, I just don't ever use this syntax as most databases do not support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Oracle 12c or up:

```
Select *
From yourtable
Order by coalesce(date, to_date('9999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')) desc
Fetch first 1 rows only
```

Thanks to @littlefoot and @tim_biegeleisen for pointing out that `TOP n` syntax is not available in Oracle; I learned about FETCH FIRST...!

Comment: There's no TOP in Oracle.

Comment: `TOP` is SQL Server (or maybe Access) syntax.  Oracle does not support `TOP`.

Answer (score 1):

I put both options into sample data; they differ on `VAR` column's value.

```
SQL> with test (var, id, datum) as
  2    (select 'A', 1, date '2022-01-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'A', 2, NULL              from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 3, date '2021-01-01' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'B', 1, date '2022-01-01' from dual union all
  7     select 'B', 2, date '2020-01-01' from dual union all
  8     select 'B', 3, date '2021-01-01' from dual
  9    ),
```

CTE ranks rows; they are partitioned by `VAR` and sorted by `datum` column's value, sorted in descending order, `NULL` values first:

```
 10  temp as
 11    (select var, id, datum,
 12            rank() over (partition by var order by datum desc nulls first) rnk
 13     from test
 14    )
```

The final query just returns rows that rank as highest:

```
 15  select var, id, datum
 16  from temp
 17  where rnk = 1;

V         ID DATUM
- ---------- ----------
A          2
B          1 01.01.2022

SQL>
```

---

Shortly:

```
with temp as
  (select var, id, datum,
          rank() over (partition by var order by datum desc nulls first) rnk
   from test
  )
select var, id, datum
from temp
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here with a two-tier sorting logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN Date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                    Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT Id, Date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The first sorting level places `NULL` date records before non `NULL` date records.  The second sorting level, to be used in the event that there are no `NULL` date records, sorts later date first.

Comment: Oracle supports standard SQL's `NULLS FIRST|LAST` clause in `ORDER BY`.